# Adding QHBoxLayout in main window

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add a `QHBoxLayout` in my Qt main window but i don't find it any where in the tool list. Please tell me. What should I do to add it to my main window?

Answer (score 3):

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html for documentation on using Qt Layouts.